# Intellij search some class not working but search everywhere working

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am using Intellij for a multi module spring java project.

I find a weird thing is that for some certain class in a module, I can't find that class by searching the class but I can find it using search everywhere or file. Also other class can't reference the missing class. It said cannot resolve symbols. However I can build and compile the project without any issue.

I tried to invalid the cache and restart but still not working.

Comment: Did you try to remove and create the file again ?

Comment: My colleague had this type of problem recently. Solved it by starting from scratch and re-importing the entire project into IntelliJ. There must have been something amiss with the configuration, perhaps in their .idea directory.